# How can I count appended elements and calculate their style?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I'm trying to create a local static page with an image uploader and a preview gallery to which append images while the user selects them. To be more specific, the image uploader is an `<input type="file" multiple="multiple">` and whenever a user selects an image I have a `<div class="preview__gallery"></div>` to which I append the selected images from the File Explorer.

Here comes the problem. After the `<img>` tags are attached to the gallery div I'd like to count them using jQuery `.length` property so I can then apply some custom style using `.css()` based on the counting results.
Seems like I can not target those images by class. I've read all across the internet and even here on SO for similar answers and in fact, I've already tried a lot of options. I've tried to use jQuery deferred functions with `$.when(firstFunction()).done(otherFunction())`, I've tried to use MutationObserver to control changes that occur on the gallery div and I've also tried event delegation but without success, because I don't have any event that triggers the function. It just has to start after the images are appended.

I'm currently calling the counting function a callback after the function that appends the images. I put a `console.log('before')` on the first function and a `console.log('after')` on the counting one, and it seems that the callback is working correctly. However, the `.length` property is not working and this is because jQuery is not being able to target the image element on the DOM. In fact, using a `console.log($('.preview__thumb'))` outputs an empty jQuery object.

Here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    function imagesPreview(input, placeToInsertImagePreview, callback) {
      if (input.files) {
        var filesAmount = input.files.length;

        for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function(event) {
            $($.parseHTML('<img class="preview__thumbs">')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
          };

          reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
          console.log('before');
        }

        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
          callback();
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="concorso__body">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <div class="single__upload">
          <div class="upload__field">
            <input type="file" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple" class="drag__area" id="file__input">

            <div class="upload__text">
              <i class="bi bi-plus"></i>

              <span>Trascina o clicca per caricare immagini</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="preview__gallery" id="the__gallery"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I figured out a workaround. I set a small timer of 50ms with `setTimeout()` before calling the callback function. Still wondering how to correctly access DOM elements after appending them though.

Comment: You could perhaps use `reader.onloadend`. It'll trigger right after a thumbnail is attached to the DOM.